# How to start a application when system boots up?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system

I have an application which I was running by using  ./cmd from the directory where it is located.
Now what I am looking for something by which the application starts automatically when my system boots up.
I came across some suggestion saying write a script, do something in init.d, etc.
But I am not able to reach a clear solution.

Request you kindly provide your valuable suggestion on same.

Comment: It totally depends on what the script should do on what level.

Comment: @JacobVlijm true but that could be part of an answer ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind You're right of course, but is was mainly meant to find out to which dupe to point to :)

Comment: is it anything else than startup application? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/816/278518

Don't forget to put the whole path in the crontab file. Meaning, after running
    crontab -e
your editor opens with the crontab file so you can add a new line to it. On that line, if your script is let's say in

```
~/mycoolscript.sh
```

you have to write the new line in your crontab file as:

```
@reboot /bin/sh /home/_your_username_/mycoolscript.sh
```

since cron does not evaluate shortcut paths and also does not run shebang scripts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you think the question is a dupe, and an existing answer applies to this question, please don't point to the answer in *a new* answer, nor *repeat* the answer here.

Comment: @JacobVlijm you're right. It's just I'm not allowed to comment :(